# labeling in R (add some labels from SPSS)

Tags: r, label, spss, named

I have some problems with my R data preparation (imported from SPSS), and wasn´t able to find a solution in the web.

*Problem: Extract labels for subgroup from data frame:*

I have a data frame with 42 variables (columns) and another data frame I made for labels. 
I generated the **label data frame** with this code:

```
labelspss <- read.spss("Ma.sav")

la <- as.data.frame(attr(labelspss, "variable.labels"))

la$`attr(labelspss, "variable.labels")`<- as.character(la$`attr(labelspss, "variable.labels")`)
```

Column 0 contains the variable names; column 1 contains the labeling from SPSS.
Now I want to extract these labels for the subgroup of 42 columns and add it to my data.

I´ve already done it manual for another data frame: created a vector for labels and labeled with package hmisc.

But now 42 variables are too much to do it this way. 
**I think I need something that makes a named character vector out of the label data frame.**
Something that extracts the variable name from rownames (for defined numbers of rows, like e.g. 140-150) and sets it to the variable label in column 1.
I think then I could use label() from the Hmisc package and do the rest.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried [haven package](http://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/labelled.html)? you can import your file with `df <- read_spss(Ma.sav)` and if its already labelled in spss you can swap all labels with `labelled_spss(df)`. I am sorry if that doesn't answer your question, its just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the rownames using `tibble::rownames_to_column()`.

Comment: Thank you, this first step worked. Now I have a data frame "la" with 2 character columns - But I need something that does what I´ve done manual here:
var.labels= c(number="ID", gr3="boy vs. girl")... So it should extract the name (1. column) that ist also in my "real" data frame and should combine it with the information in the 2. column (label/ description)...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood what you want. 
Do you mean that if for example you have data.frame like this:
df <- data.frame(colA = c("apple", "bread", "milk"), 
                 colB = c("Two", "one", "four"))

You want this to happen? 
df %>% 
  mutate(combine = paste(colA, colB, sep = ""))